# login authentication uses wrong table

Tags: php, laravel

When I'm testing the login authentication in my Laravel webpage, the webpage throws this error:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `admins`
WHERE
  `FacultyUsername` = Franco
limit
  1
```

Even though FacultyUsername should not connected to the table **admins**, but instead it should be connected to table **faculties**, what can be done to fix this?

Here is my code for...

> auth.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'admins',
        'passwords' => 'admins',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'faculties' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'faculties',
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'faculties' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Faculties::class,
            'table' => 'faculties'
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Admins::class,
            'table' => 'admins'
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expiry time is the number of minutes that each reset token will be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    | The throttle setting is the number of seconds a user must wait before
    | generating more password reset tokens. This prevents the user from
    | quickly generating a very large amount of password reset tokens.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_reset_tokens',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
    | times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
    | confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
    |
    */

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

> FacultiesController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\Models\Faculties;
use Validator;

class FacultiesController extends Controller
{
    public function facultyLogin(Request $request){
        $facultycredentials = $request->only('FacultyUsername','FacultyPasswword');

        if (Auth::attempt($facultycredentials)) {
            return redirect()->intended('/facultydashboard');
        }
        return back();
    }

    public function storeFaculty(Request $request)
    {
        
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'FacultyName' => 'required',
            'FacultyDateofBirth' => 'required|date',
            'FacultyAddress' => 'required',
            'FacultyEmail' => 'required|email|unique:faculties,FacultyEmail',
            'FacultyUsername' => 'required|unique:faculties,FacultyUsername',
            'FacultyPassword' => 'required',
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $data = [
                "status" => 422,
                "message" => $validator->messages()
            ];
            
            return response()->json($data, 422);
        }
         else{
            $faculties = new Faculties;

            $faculties->FacultyName = $request->FacultyName;
            $faculties->FacultyDateofBirth = $request->FacultyDateofBirth;
            $faculties->FacultyAddress = $request->FacultyAddress;
            $faculties->FacultyEmail = $request->FacultyEmail;
            $faculties->FacultyUsername = $request->FacultyUsername;
            $faculties->FacultyPassword = Hash::make($request->FacultyPassword);

            $faculties->save();

            $data = [
                "status" => 200,
                "message" => 'Registration Successful'
            ];


            return response()->json($data, 200);

         }
    
    }

}
```

> Faculties.php(My Model Used, admin should only be connected to Admins.php model)

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableTrait;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class Faculties extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract
{
    use HasFactory, AuthenticatableTrait, HasRoles;

    protected $fillable = [
        'FacultyName',
        'FacultyDateofBirth',
        'FacultyAddress',
        'FacultyEmail',
        'FacultyUsername',
        'FacultyPassword',
    ];
}
```

> route used in web.php

```
Route::get('/facultyLogin', function () {return view('facultyLogin');})->name('login.faculty');
```

> route used in api.php

```
Route::post('faculty', [FacultiesController::class, 'storeFaculty']);
Route::post('facultyLogin', [FacultiesController::class, 'facultyLogin'])->name('post.faculty');
```

> form used in my webpage

```
<form action="{{route ('post.faculty')}}" method="POST">
                        <div class="inputField">
                            <label for="studentNumber">Username: </label>
                        </div><div class="inputField">
                            <input type="text" name="FacultyUsername" placeholder="Ex. " required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="inputField">
                            <label for="password">Password: </label>
                        </div><div class="inputField">
                            <input type="password" name="FacultyPassword" placeholder="Ex. " required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="loginButtons">
                            <button class="btn" onclick="openFacultyDashboard()">Sign in</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

> faculties table

```
public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('faculties', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('FacultyID');
            $table->string('FacultyName')->required();
            $table->date('FacultyDateofBirth')->required();
            $table->string('FacultyAddress')->required();
            $table->string('FacultyEmail')->unique();
            $table->string('FacultyUsername')->unique();
            $table->string('FacultyPassword')->required();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: the default guard is 'admins' so you need to specify that you want to use 'faculties' guard when dealing with auth methods. like `Auth::guard('faculties')->attempt($facultycredentials)`

Comment: So if I remove the default it also works?

Comment: removing the default wont fix your issue, using the right guard at the right place will. like when you put middleware auth in routes, you need to set it to auth:faculties instead

Answer (score 0):

In `Auth::attempt($facultycredentials),` the default guard is `admin`. If you're using some other, then you have to specify it.

```
if (Auth::guard('faculties')->attempt($facultyCredentials)) {
    return redirect()->intended('/facultydashboard');
}
```